# Pasting in Data Validation IF the value exists inside the data validation list

Tags: vba, excel

A similar question has been asked multiple times, but I have a slightly different ask. I have used some code from superuser that restricts users from pasting values into data validation ranges:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Does the validation range still have validation?
    If HasValidation(Range("DataValidationRange")) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Application.Undo
        MsgBox "Error: You cannot paste data into these cells." & _
        "Please use the drop-down to enter data instead.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub

Private Function HasValidation(r) As Boolean
    'Returns True if every cell in Range r uses Data Validation
    On Error Resume Next
    x = r.Validation.Type
    If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True Else HasValidation = False
End Function
```

This is great and it works, but I am wondering if it can be taken one step further. The reason users may want to paste into these fields is because they are moving data from one spreadsheet to the other. I have the validation there to ensure the spelling is correct (important for other uses). Is it possible for a user to paste something into the data validation field and it doesn't deny it, based on the code above, IF the value matches something inside the data validation list? Seems ambitious, not sure if it is possible.

Edit: The list is stored in another tab, not hardcoded into the data validation menu

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` is fired too late - how do you recover the previous value if the new one is invalid?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon the list is stored in another tab, could that be used?

Comment: hmm, just noticed the `Application.Undo` invoke, ignore my previous comment. You need to get an array that contains each element of the validation list - however to do that you need to know whether you're looking at a hard-coded, comma-separated list of values, or whether the validation list is defined by a named range, or a range address. Note: the undo stack will be cleared if any macro changes any cell anywhere.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon the data validation field i am focusing on now is just an entire column in a separate tab. Not hardcoded values or a name ranged list. What do you mean by the undo stack will be cleared if any macro changes any cell?

Comment: Then you can get the range address from the validation list, and compare the `Target` /pasted value with the values in that range.

Comment: What I'm not sure of, is whether that handler works *as intended* at all, given `Target` isn't even used or intersected with anything: the handler runs whenever a cell value changes anywhere on the sheet, and then does its thing regardless of where the modified cell actually is: this normally results in unexpected behavior when a cell is modified outside the range that's assumed by the code.

Comment: @cexcelc, "clearing the undo stack" is the thing that happens when the program can't undo anymore now that the undo stack is cleared.  This is bad if you were hoping to undo.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I will try to compare the pasted value with the data validation list and see if that works. I am not that great at VBA, will post back here if I run into issues. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Validation` isn't `Nothing` and its type is `xlValidateList` (underlying value `3`), then you can use `Validation.Formula1` to get the "list".

That's the easy part.

If `Formula1` doesn't start with an `=` sign, you're looking at a plain comma-separated list of values.

This function gets you a 1-dimensional array with all the valid values of the specified `target`, regardless of how the data validation list is defined:

```
Public Function GetValidationValues(ByVal target As Range) As Variant
    Dim dataValidation As Validation
    Set dataValidation = target.Validation

    If dataValidation Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If dataValidation.Type <> xlValidateList Then Exit Function

    Dim values As Variant
    If Left$(dataValidation.Formula1, 1) <> "=" Then
        'plain comma-separated list of values
        values = Split(dataValidation.Formula1, ",")
    Else
        'validation list is a range address, or a named range
        Dim rngValues As Range
        Set rngValues = Application.Evaluate(dataValidation.Formula1)
        If rngValues.Columns.Count > 1 Then
            values = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rngValues))
        Else
            values = Application.Transpose(rngValues)
        End If
    End If
    GetValidationValues = values
End Function
```

All that's left to do is to determine whether your pasted value is in that array.

Comment: I don't think i've used target.Validation for anything? Target is a range but it's not set to anything. There are multiple columns that have data validation lists in this spreadsheet, but I only care about one of the columns. How does this function know which list to refer to?

Comment: @cexcelc the function takes a `Range` parameter: you give it a cell that has data validation in it, and it returns an array that contains all the possible values; there's not enough information in your question for me to know what specific cell to feed it - I don't know what `Range("DataValidationRange")` refers to. As [I said earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750097/pasting-in-data-validation-if-the-value-exists-inside-the-data-validation-list/51750965?noredirect=1#comment90461001_51750097), something looks off.

Comment: Ok, if they can paste just 1 cell, or a range of cells (goes down to cell 3000), should I create a loop to check if each value pasted exists in the array?

Comment: Your handler is completely ignoring the handler's `Target` argument, which is what tells you what cell(s) was/were modified. But yes, you'll want to iterate all the cells in the handler's `Target`. There's a disconnect though: if the user pasted cells and thus removed the validation, you can't use the handler's `Target` to know what the validation rule is supposed to be. This function's `target` needs to be a cell that reliably contains your validation rule.

Comment: You can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Index` with the returned array to know if a cell in the handler's `Target` contains a value that exists in the data validation list. Or you can iterate the returned array. Or you can... see, there's multiple ways to skin a cat - use what works best for your case.

Comment: I see, for more context (based on your edited comment): Range("DataValidationRange") is cells P22:P3000 (a named range). If you try and paste in that range (where data validation exists), you get the error. The data validation inside each cell between P22:P3000 refers to a separate tab that has 'lookups', specifically column E:E. So ideally, when something is pasted anywhere in P22:P3000, it should check to see if the value pasted exists in column E:E on the other sheet, and if it does allow the paste, if not then the HasValidation function should kick in

Comment: @cexcelc except your approach will only work once; after I pasted a bunch of values, these cells no longer have data validation, and after pasting would-be-illegal values on top of those, the handler happily bails out because there's no validation anymore.

Comment: I see, so if something is pasted, even if acceptable, the data validation will be removed therefore allowing a second paste of anything. This would probably be pretty rare, but could happen. Is it possible to add the data validation back to the cells post-paste?

Comment: Worse: if something is pasted from a cell that contains some other data validation list, it's pasted *along with its own validation list*, and now you're looking at pasted data that has data validation, but not the rules you mean to enforce. RE re-add the *correct* validation: yes, it's possible - but for that you need to have the rule *somewhere*, perhaps in some hidden cell: *and that's the cell the function in this answer means to be working with.*

Comment: It is very easy to add the correct validation rule somewhere else. Is that what target is supposed to be set to? Or is target my pasted range?

Comment: The function's `target` parameter means to be a cell that contains the data validation rule you mean to apply, yes.

Comment: Is the Worksheet_Change target supposed to be set to the range that I am pasting to. I have yet to get this to work, not sure what to put into the Worksheet_Change sub

Comment: ++ Naicee. Refered this post to [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63313207/importing-data-overwriting-drop-down-list-data)

Comment: @Sid thanks! I think the hard-coded comma might need to be replaced with the *list separator* character with `Application.International`, and that should work whether your system uses `,` or `;` for a separator.