# Importing data overwriting drop down list data

Tags: excel, vba

I am importing data in excel from another excel file using below code.

Also I have setup the drop down list on column C and E. When I run this macro it overwrites the drop down list data.

I want that It should give error if user doesn't import the correct name and city and also give suggestion of that () ?

Is there any possibility If I can implement this logic .

```
Dim FileToOpen As String
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file")

If FileToOpen <> flase Then
Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)

OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:F21").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("B4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

OpenBook.Close False
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` will not trigger the error if the pasted data doesnt match the datavalidation list data. Quick question. Does all cell have the same validation?

Comment: All cells not have same validation

Comment: I am already pasting data as suggested by you ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("B4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: the that will not solve your purpose. Let me check. I am trying something....

Comment: Ok i did a brief testing and it should work. So here is the logic. You will have to store the copying range in an array and then check if the values are present in the data validation cells using `.Validation`   (i.e if the destination cell has validation) and then if all check is passed then paste the values...

Comment: can you please help me with code as well ? how should I store value in array and than validate?

Comment: I can easily spend 30 minutes to code and test and post a solution but that would not be helpful for you... Google **vba excel range to array** and **vba .Validation** and **vba .Formula1** and then try and come up with a code. We will continue from there

Comment: Thank for your time and will try to implement as per your logic and will post here .thank you

Comment: And also see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750097/pasting-in-data-validation-if-the-value-exists-inside-the-data-validation-list) by @MathieuGuindon which you can use in the logic that i mentioned above to check if the value satisfies the condition or not....

Comment: Siddharth Rout, I post an answer and I need your help there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219480/discussion-between-deepak-verma-and-siddharth-rout).

Answer (score 0):

Somehow with the help of google I am able to achieve what i want . But I have still some issue.

When I manually select data from drop down list and click on submit button  . It show msg "Invalid cell value"

---

```
Dim isect As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim dd As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim mtch As Boolean
Dim msg As String
Dim myEntries As String
    
'   See if any updated cells fall in C4:C23
    Set isect = Intersect(Range("C4:C23"), Target)
    
'   Exit if updated cells do not fall in C4:C23
    If isect Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
'   Set drop-down values
    dd = Array("A","B","C","D")
    
'   Loop through all intersecting cells
    For Each cell In isect
'       See if cell entry matches any drop-down values
        mtch = False
        For i = LBound(dd) To UBound(dd)
            If cell.Value = dd(i) Then
                mtch = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
'       If value is not in list, erase and return message
        If mtch = False Then
            cell.ClearContents
            
           msg = "Invalid cell value"
        End If
    Next cell
    
'   Build string of validation entries
    For i = LBound(dd) To UBound(dd)
        myEntries = myEntries & dd(i) & ","
    Next i
    myEntries = Left(myEntries, Len(myEntries) - 1)
    
'   Reset validation
    With Range("C4:C23").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=myEntries
'        .IgnoreBlank = True
'        .InCellDropdown = True
'        .InputTitle = ""
'        .ErrorTitle = ""
'        .InputMessage = ""
'        .ErrorMessage = ""
'        .ShowInput = True
'        .ShowError = True
    End With
    
'   Return message, if necessary
    If Len(msg) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid entries in cells: " & vbCrLf & Left(msg, Len(msg) - 1), vbOKOnly, "ERROR!"
        Else
     
    End If
```

---